# I am trying to add a string of integers into an array, but it is incorrect

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a string:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

and I want it added into my array such that it becomes:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

However, when I run my code,

```
int[] leftValues = new int[9];
    for (String w:left.split("\\s",0)){
      for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
        leftValues[i] = Integer.valueOf(w);
      }
    }
```

My output gives me :

```
[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
```

May I know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested loops first assign the first integer to all indices of the array, then the second integer, ... , and finally the last integer (9). Therefore your array ends up holding only 9s.

You need a single loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (String w : left.split("\\s",0)) {
    leftValues[i] = Integer.valueOf(w);
    i++;
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
for (String w : left.split("\\s",0)) {
    leftValues[i++] = Integer.valueOf(w);
}
```

Comment: Also, `0` is implied in the split, so not needed imo.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I'm not sure what you meant by that comment.

Comment: `split(String)` should be used instead of `split(String, int)` since  `0` is already the default value

Answer (score 1):

Here is Java 8 way of doing this concisely

```
String numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
int[] integers = Arrays.stream(numbers.split("\\s"))
                       .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                       .toArray();
```

Comment: There are ways to do it more easily and also you're outputting a `List` not an array

Comment: didn't realise array was desired. The solution becomes even easier. Modified the solution, essentially it is just a line of solution now.

Comment: Nice, you can use the method reference `Integer::parseInt` to be more concised

Comment: It's about personal test. Integer::parseInt is more cryptic to some than s -> Integer.parseInt() and it's hard to have a consensus which is more concise.